# Issue with Configobj-python and list items

Tags: python, python-3.x, config, ini, configobj

I am trying to read `.ini` file with keywords having single items or list items. When I try to print single item strings and float values, it prints as `h,e,l,l,o` and `2, ., 1` respectively, whereas it should have been just `hello` and `2.1`. Also, when I try to write new single item string/float/integer, there is `,` at the end. I am new to python and dealing with `configobj`. Any help is appreciated and if this question has been answered previously, please direct me to it. Thanks!

```
from configobj import ConfigObj
```

**Read**

```
config = ConfigObj('para_file.ini')
para = config['Parameters']
print(", ".join(para['name']))
print(", ".join(para['type']))
print(", ".join(para['value']))
```

**Write**

```
new_names = 'hello1'
para['name'] = [x.strip(' ') for x in new_names.split(",")]
new_types = '3.1'
para['type'] = [x.strip(' ') for x in new_types.split(",")]
new_values = '4'
para['value'] = [x.strip(' ') for x in new_values.split(",")]
config.write()
```

My `para_file.ini` looks like this,

```
[Parameters]

name = hello1
type = 2.1
value = 2
```

Comment: I'm quite confused by why you're expecting to get multiple values for any of your parameters. It looks to me like you only ever want to read one value for each name, and only intend to write one value as well. In that case, why not just do `print(para['name'])` and `para['name'] = new_names`? Is there some context where you *do* expect multiple values?

Comment: @Blckknght, thanks for your reply! Yes, I am trying to input the parameters to a GUI and the user config parameters can have either single item or list items. At the same time, user can modify the parameters and save it as either single item/list items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two parts to your question.

1. Options in ConfigObj can be either a string, or a list of strings.

   ```
   [Parameters]
     name = hello1             # This will be a string
     pets = Fluffy, Spot       # This will be a list with 2 items
     town = Bismark, ND        # This will also be a list of 2 items!!
     alt_town = "Bismark, ND"  # This will be a string
     opt1 = foo,               # This will be a list of 1 item (note the trailing comma)
   ```

   So, if you want something to appear as a list in ConfigObj, you must make sure it includes a comma. A list of one item must have a trailing comma.
2. In Python, strings are iterable. So, even though they are not a list, they can be iterated over. That means in an expression like

   ```py
   print(", ".join(para['name']))
   ```

   The string `para['name']` will be iterated over, producing the  list `['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '1']`, which Python dutifully joins together with spaces, producing

   ```
   h e l l o 1
   ```